# Spring boot server running in windows cmd responds to requests from remote browser but doesn't respond when running in eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse

I am running a Spring boot application in eclipse. The REST APIs in the application successfully get called when requested from local browser. But when I try to call them from a remote browser in the same network the browser shows connection problem. More interesting fact is that when I run jar of this application in windows cmd then it successfully responds from remote browser

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. Changed port no in application.properties to server.port=8081.

Comment: Changing the Port works because there might be a running process on the remote browser with the same port